# Android App with Fragments/Actionbar: How to run code when startup is totally finished?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am writing an android app that uses Fragments and an ActionBar.

Is there a simple way to know when the entire app has finished starting up?  Each fragment has it's own layout, and my startup code needs to touch them all.  Is there an event I could use to accomplish this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreateView is called after the view is "all there", so its a good place for code that needs to run late in the game.  You could set a flag here or send an event to notify other views that you're ready, but it is per fragment.

However, fragments are kind of based on the idea that they will be created as needed.  In a normal app they come and go dynamically so there isnt ever a time when the "whole app is loaded".  So, there isnt going to be a single place you can check for whether all fragments are ready unless you make your own.  Before doing that you might want to consider other ways to accomplish the task at hand. Your design may not be a good one if you are having to fight against the underlying system.

Comment: Understood.  My design is such that there are several screens, each with a Fragment and it's own Layout.  One fragment is a "Setup" screen where the user's choices are loaded from a web serer via JSON and displayed.  The next screen shows an account status message (which is received when the first screen is loaded), and allows the user to interact with the web service.  Does this help explain why I'm asking this particular question?

Comment: Well.. Honestly that describes that form of most applications more or less. Generally you would store your application state (things like the account status) somewhere that the fragments can obtain it as needed/when created. Trying to push it into a fragment from outside will be much harder than pulling it from inside.

Comment: This makes sense.  I have a solution in mind to this that I will try.  Thank you for your suggestion.